# arithmetic expression: expecting primary:

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to do a script in shell that sleeps for a random period of time and after this calls a python script. I am doing this:

```
#!/bin/bash

now="$(date)"
printf "Current date and time %s\n" "$now"

maxdelay=25
delay=$(($RANDOM%maxdelay)) # pick an independent random delay for each of the 20 runs
echo $delay;
(sleep $((delay*60)); /usr/bin/python pythonscript.py) &
```

But it is failing, this is the result:

```
Current date and time mar jun  9 00:02:10 CEST 2015
prueba.sh: 7: prueba.sh: arithmetic expression: expecting primary: "%maxdelay"
```

Yesterday it works perfect but today I don't know why it is failing

Comment: I don't see a problem. Are you sure you haven't modified your script? Check the timestamp with `ls -l`.  At least half of your script seems irrelevant. What happens if you type `maxdelay=25; delay=$(($RANDOM%maxdelay)); echo $delay` at a shell prompt?

Comment: If Windows was involved processing this script before copying to Unix/linux, then `dos2unix prueba.sh` . Good luck.

Comment: If I type that directly in the shell, works perfectly, and I've noticed that if the shell script is called from the crontab works well too, but if I execute the script in the shell throw me that error.
I'm in ubuntu , windows is not involve

Comment: Place `set -x` immediately after the shebang line to see what's really going on.

Comment: Have you verified (by checking the timestamp with `ls -l`) that you haven't modified the script since the last time it worked?

Comment: Can someone also tell me why it's not generating a random value when I'm doing it this way: $ bash -c "maxdelay=25; delay=$(($RANDOM%maxdelay)); echo $delay". It prints 18 each time. Tried with both sh -c or bash -c "..."
18

Comment: @ArunSangal: By using double quotes, `$delay` is being evaluated in the current shell. Try this to see what's happening: `delay=FOOBAR; bash -c "maxdelay=25; delay=$(($RANDOM%maxdelay)); echo $delay"`. To fix it, use single quotes.

Answer (score 19):

You seem to be running that script using `dash` instead of `bash`, possibly because you're invoking the script as

```
sh prueba.sh
```

instead of

```
# prueba.sh must have exec permissions
# the shebang line is used to select the interpreter
./prueba.sh
```

or

```
bash prueba.sh
```

`RANDOM` is a bash extension; in `dash`, it is not special and not assigned by default.

In an arithmetic expression, if `$var` is used and `var` is unassigned, then it is substituted with an empty string, which often creates a syntax error. On the other hand, if you use `var` and `var` has not been assigned a value, it is assumed to be 0.

Debian and Ubuntu installs typically use `dash` for the `/bin/sh` default shell interpreter.

Note that `bash` and `dash` produce different error messages:

```
$ bash -c 'unset foo;bar=25;echo $(($foo*$bar))'
bash: *25: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "*25")
$ dash -c 'unset foo;bar=25;echo $(($foo*$bar))'
dash: 1: arithmetic expression: expecting primary: "*25"
```

Comment: The lesson: If a script has a `#!` line at the top, just run the script directly rather than manually feeding it to `sh`. (And if it doesn't have a `#!` line, it probably should.)

Comment: Had this issue on Windows with Ubuntu terminal, sh ./file.sh didn't run, bash ./file.sh did :-)

Answer (score -3):

Add the executable permission
By chomd +× "filename"
Then run by ./"filename"

Comment: this answer does not attend to the question, since they can clearly run the command still. I'd also recommend if you're providing commands, ensure words are spelled correctly and proper syntax is used. I suggest using some of the formatting tools as well to provide clearer distinction of commentary and code.